# Is there the HTML which is being ignored by CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assume that in below HTML, the element with class `ChildBar` could be or could not be.

```html
<div class="Parent">
    <div class="ChildFoo"></div>
    <div class="ChildBar"></div> <!-- Could not be -->
    <div class="ChildBaz"></div>
</div>
```

Also, assume that `ChildBaz` must retire from `ChildFoo` by `4px` but from `ChildBar` - by `6px`. In CSS, it will be:

```css
.ChildFoo + .ChildBaz {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.ChildBar + .ChildBaz {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

Now, I want to mount by JavaScript the element `ChildBar` to correct position, herewith:

1. The changing of the markup around the `ChildBar` must not brake the JavaScript behaviour. It means the methods like `Element.after()` referes to sibling elements could not be used.
2. I need the *mounting*, not displaying from the hidden state.
3. The above styles must not be broken.

In the case of below markup, `replaceWith` solution would be easy.

```html
<div class="Parent">
    <div class="ChildFoo"></div>
    <div id="ChildBarMountingPoint"></div>
    <div class="ChildBaz"></div>
</div>
```

Hoewever, the element with ID `ChildBarMountingPoint` brakes the styles.  Is there some `magic` element which is being ignored by CSS thus `.ChildFoo + ChildBaz` is being correctly appied? (If no, the solutions branch with `replaceWith` is a dead end and I must find the other solutions branch).

Comment: it's hard to understand what you mean to achieve. Anyway since I see you are using the adjacent sibling combinator [+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) maybe the general sibling combinator could be of help [~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator). Anyway the css rules you showed are both addressing the same element because those selectors style `.ChildBaz`.

Comment: I don't understand either. Some screenshots of the desired result would really help.

Comment: Will .ChildBaz ALWAYS be the 3rd element within .Parent? Because you might want to consider using :nth-child(n)  for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @KayAngevare, No. Maybe `.ChildBaz` will be replaced in the future. Is will brake the CSS but must not brake the JavaScript.

Comment: So why not just give .ChildBar a bottom-margin of 2px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a "magic" element that doesn't exist for the purpose of CSS selectors - No. But *only* elements are matched by selectors, and there are other node types. Maybe you could use one of those.

For example, one possibility is to use a comment. Assuming that you know that the two/three elements will be in a known parent whose class is `.Parent` you could do:

```js
document.querySelector('#addChildBar').addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  Array.from(document.querySelector('.Parent').childNodes).find(n => {
    return n.nodeType === 8 && n.data === ' ChildBarMountingPoint '
  }).replaceWith(Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {
    className: 'ChildBar' 
  }));
  
})
```

```css
.ChildFoo + .ChildBaz {
  margin-top: 4px;
  color: red;
}

.ChildBar + .ChildBaz {
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent"> 
    <div class="ChildFoo">foo</div>
    <!-- ChildBarMountingPoint -->
    <div class="ChildBaz">baz</div>
</div>
<hr>
<button type="button" id="addChildBar">Add ChildBar</button>
```

Comment nodes are node type 8.

If you don't know the parent, then you'll need to walk the DOM node by node to find the correct comment node.

Comment: Your post is not only answers on my question but also fully solves my problem. Thank you very much for the perfect answer!